# Error using cql prepared statement in cassandra (astyanax)

Tags: cassandra, astyanax

I was experimenting with astyana write operation, and was using cqlsh for that.
If i simply use the query, I am able to get the result

```
keyspace.prepareQuery(COLUMN_FAMILY).withCql("insert into scan_request (customer_id, uuid, scan_type, status, content_size, request_time, request_content_hash) values ("+dao.getCustomerId()+","+"'"+dao.getUuId()+"',"+dao.getScanType()+","+dao.getStatus()+","+dao.getContentSize()+",'2012-12-12 12:12:12', '"+dao.getRequestContentHash()+"');")
            .execute();
```

However if i use prepared statement to do the same, i get the below error.

```
        this.getKeyspace()
        .prepareQuery(COLUMN_FAMILY)
            .withCql(INSERT_STATEMENT)
        .asPreparedStatement()
            .withIntegerValue(dao.getCustomerId())
            .withStringValue(dao.getUuId())
            .withIntegerValue(dao.getScanType())
            .withIntegerValue(dao.getStatus())
            .withIntegerValue(dao.getContentSize())
            .withStringValue("'2012-12-12 12:12:12'")
            .withStringValue(dao.getRequestContentHash())
        .execute();
```

I get the below error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to write data to C*
    at com.tools.dbaccess.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxClient.write(AstyanaxClient.java:155)
    at com.tools.dbaccess.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxClient.main(AstyanaxClient.java:164)
Caused by: com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.exceptions.BadRequestException: BadRequestException: [host=localhost(127.0.0.1):9160, latency=11(11), attempts=1]InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (21))
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftConverter.ToConnectionPoolException(ThriftConverter.java:159)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:65)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:28)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$ThriftConnection.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:151)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:69)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:256)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$3.execute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:80)
    at com.tools.dbaccess.cassandra.astyanax.AstyanaxClient.write(AstyanaxClient.java:144)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: InvalidRequestException(why:Expected 8 or 0 byte long for date (21))
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_prepared_cql3_query_result.read(Cassandra.java:41868)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1689)
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_prepared_cql3_query(Cassandra.java:1674)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftCql3Query.execute_prepared_cql_query(ThriftCql3Query.java:29)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$3$1.internalExecute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:92)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractThriftCqlQuery$3$1.internalExecute(AbstractThriftCqlQuery.java:82)
    at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:60)
```

I think its wrong when i try to store the timestamp into the table. But i didn't find anything adequeate in the preparedStatement to store timestamp. The datatype of the field in the database is "timestamp".

Comment: Don't just dump code on us, give us some context. Your code example has pieces of it commented out, why? Make an effort before asking for our help.

Comment: @Theo Correcting the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have used

.withByteBufferValue(new Date(), DateSerializer.get()).

Or if you have a custom object to serialize, extend the AbstractSerializer class.

Answer (score 0):

Since what you get is a `NullPointerException` have you checked that some of your values aren't null?